# Usage of Farkas' lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations

Given a system of n linear equations. Prove that the system is inconsistent
if and only if you can obtain 0 = 1, by using linear combinations.

I do not want to apply theorems from linear algebra here. Instead of it I want to use Farkas' lemma.

Every equation can be rewrited in form of two inequalities with $\leq$ and $\geq$, now I got $2n$ inequalities instead of $n$ equations.

I think that's the moment for me to apply Farkas' lemma, but why I can always get $0 \leq 1$ and $0 \geq 1$?

Comment: What exactly form of Farkas lemma do you think to apply to $Ax\le b$? Try to rewrite it first to obtain one of the canonical forms.

Comment: I can just multiply $\geq$ inequalities with $-1$, right?

Comment: Formulate Farkas lemma you are using.

Comment: If I understood your words correctly...Paragraph 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma)

Comment: Paragraph 2 says, in particular $\ge 0$, not $\ge b$. Moreover, it has some strict inequality that $Ax\le b$ does not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **very easy** to prove the result from linear algebra (Gauss eliminations). If you prefer to work it out using Farkas lemma then you can do the following: the equation $Ax=b$ fits the best to the first alternative of the [Farkas lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas'_lemma), we only missing the positivity of $x$. To get positivity one can write $x=v-w$, where $v,w\ge 0$. It is the standard rewriting in Linear Programming. You get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A & -A\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v\\ w\end{pmatrix}=b,\quad v,w\ge 0.
$$
This is exactly the first alternative. If it has no solution then the dual system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A^T\\-A^T\end{pmatrix}y\le\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad b^Ty>0
$$
has a solution. The dual system is the same as
$$
A^Ty=0,\quad b^Ty>0\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad y^TA=0,\quad y^Tb>0.
$$
One can always scale $y$ to get $y^Tb=1$.

It means that if you multiply your original equation $Ax=b$ by $y^T$ from the left you will get
$$
\underbrace{y^TA}_{=0}x=\underbrace{y^Tb}_{=1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0=1.
$$